# How to retrieve the lastly updated folder in a hierarchy of folders?

Tags: vbscript

i have a directory with subfolders. These subfolders have subfolders as well. For all Folders exist a timestamp with the time when they were last modified.

For example:

Folder1(21.01.2010)
-subfolder1(22.01.2010)
-subfolder2(23.01.2010)
--subfolder1(24.01.2010)
--subfolder2(25.01.2010)
Folder2(26.01.2010)
-subfolder 1(27.01.2010)

What I need is a script that checks the latest "date modified". 
So the Output should be "27.01.2010".

I dont know how to start... is there a function which can list all folders??

Maybe you can help me... thank you in advance!

Comment: You will need to apply recursion, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion. Can you give some example code of what you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of folders and modified dates

```
Sub GetLastModified(folderspec)
    Dim fs, f, f1, fc, s
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFolder(folderspec)
    Set fc = f.SubFolders
    For Each f1 in fc
        s = s & f1.Name 
        s = s & f1.DateLastModified
        s = s &  vbCrLf
    Next
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Then you just need to iterate to find all folders WITHIN those folders and keep a record of the *latest* modified date

Answer (score 1):

keep the template:

```
  dim fs, foldercollection ,filecollection, folders, files

  Set fs=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set fileobject = fs.GetFolder("c:\")

  Set foldercollection = fileobject.SubFolders 
  folders = ""
  files = ""
  For Each folder in foldercollection 
    folders = folders & folder.name & Chr(13)
  Next 
  Set foldercollection=nothing
  Set filecollection = fileobject.Files
  For Each file in filecollection 
    files = files & file.name & Chr(13)
  next

  MsgBox folders & files
```